# Determining left or right side of an ECMAScript assignment expression

Tags: javascript, parsing, antlr4

I'm working on a parsing application that builds a symbol table for the text of an ECMAScript file.  The problem I'm having is determining when I'm on the right or left side of an assignment operator when processing an identifier with a `ParseTreeListener`.

This is using [Chris Lambrou's ANTLR grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g) which appears to track pretty closely with the official grammar in the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3).  There is a parser rule called `leftHandSideExpression`, but this is deceptive as it also consistently shows up on the right hand side of expressions when displayed in the TestRig GUI.

Is this a task that requires the visitor pattern?

Appreciate the advice.

Comment: When the interpreter pattern is not sufficient, then a parser should be the next solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `leftHandSideExpression` can only appear in the following locations:

- On the left hand side of an `assignmentOperator`. Note that this can *also* be the right hand side, such as the expression `y` in `x = y = 3`.
- The expression part of a postfix increment/decrement operator (the `x` in `x++` or `x--`).
- The initializer part of a `for (... in` statement.

To determine if you are currently looking at the left hand side of an assignment expression, examine the current parse tree node and its parents for a `LeftHandSideExpressionContext` whose parent is either `AssignmentExpressionContext` or `AssignmentExpressionNoInContext`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the intent of leftHandSideExpression.  However, what I'm seeing in practice is that in a simple "foo = bar;", the right side traverses assignmentExpression -> conditionalExpression -> logicalORExpression -> logicalANDExpression -> bitwiseORExpression -> bitwiseXORExpression -> bitwiseANDExpression -> equalityExpression -> relationalExpression -> shiftExpression -> additiveExpression -> multiplicativeExpression -> unaryExpression -> postfixExpression -> leftHandSideExpression.  All that foils my listener on leftHandSideExpression.

Comment: @TimClemons In that chain, the *parent* of `LeftHandSideExpressionContext` reveals the situation (see the last statement of my answer).

Comment: Aha! That makes complete sense.  Thanks.